# Hexagon map coordinates -> html rendering

Tags: javascript, html, hex

I have an hexagonal map but I realized that my coordinate system is bad for using some findpath algorithms so I want to reform it. 
I chose one system that fully satisfies me. You can find it [here](http://vanreijmersdal.nl/development/experiments/javascript/hexpath/). But at the referenced example the whole map is rotated differently than I need.

My old version of my map is here:
http://dark-project.cz/wesnoth/map-view/1

And my question is how to render my map in HTML to have the same map as I have now but with the new coordinate system?

(I render it using PHP cycle. For each field I have this informations:
coordinates, field type (grass, village, ...) and dimensions of field image)

Thank you for your answers!

PS: I think it could be done by using HTML5 Canvas but I want good browser support and I haven't got any experience with HTML5 (but I'm not againt rendering on the client side if it was fast and had good browser support) so I prefer server side (PHP) solution!

Comment: Using canvas means you draw your map with javascript drawing methods, placing images in the canvas. Seeing how you now use html hovers I wonder if you really want to put it into a javascript version?

Comment: kontur: I didn't say that I wanted to use javascript. I PREFER to render the map in PHP like in the old version, but I don't know how to do it using the new coordinate system...

Comment: What do you mean by you don't know how to use the coordinate system?

Comment: How to get the absolute position values from the coordinates. For example: the field is 40x40px (size of one hex) and this field has coordinates x:5, y:4. What is its position relative to the whole map?

Comment: But in your linked example, you are already drawing the map? What is wrong with that?

Comment: I'm asking how can I get from the coordinates the position of field relative to map. I need it sometimes in the application also...

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut25.html

Comment: But this example uses the same principe of coordinates that I had originally and it is bad because I can't get simply the distance between two hexes so I need to reform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coordinate system is not compatible with the one used in the algorithm demo.

I think your best bet is to alter the algorithm you have found to use your coordinate system.

AFAIK you essentially have to change:

- the part that takes a given coordinate and determines the 6 neighbouring coordinates.
- the function that determines if a given coordinate is inside the map boundaries.
- (sort of) the function that calculates the cost/distance

I notice the demo code goes:

```
function hex_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    dx = Math.abs(x1-x2);
    dy = Math.abs(y2-y1);
    return Math.sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy));
}
```

But that's an inaccurate estimate as the axes aren't perpendicular.  It could produce non-optimal results - the requirement of a score function in A* search is to produce a value *not higher than* the real cost.  This function may violate that rule.

Your coordinate system would actually make that function more accurate, but you could also get away with just the manhattan distance:

```
function hex_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    return abs(x2-x1) + abs(y2-y1);
}
```

Which, if I am not mistaken, works out to the number of tile steps needed to get from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2).

Comment: Sure, but there is one problem: How to calculate distance between two fields using my coordinate system? (used for calculating H in A* algorithm)

Comment: Wow...its so simple? :D OK...thank you very much, this is the best solution :)